# I need help on proves about automata

Tags: automata

Prove or disprove the following statements about the set of languages decided
by each of the automata:

```
1) DPDA ⊆ 2-stack DPDA
2) 2-stack DPDA ⊆ DPDA
3) NPDA ⊆ 2-stack DPDA
4) 2-stack DPDA ⊆ NPDA
```

Comment: What is your current theory? Please take a look at [**How do I ask** and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Also, this question might be better suited for the [Computer Science StackOverflow site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) since this is more about theory and less about code.

Answer (score 1):

1) A DPDA has one stack, so a DPDA with two stacks can definitely do anything a DPDA can do just by not using (or trivially using) the second stack.
2) A two stack DPDA can recognize the language of words with the same numbers of a's, b's and c's by using the first stack to ensure the number of a's is equal to the number of b's, and the second stack to ensure the number of b's is equal to the number of c's. Because this language is not context-free, there is no one-stack DPDA for it; therefore, 2-stack DPDA is not equal. Because we know DPDA is subset-or-equal to 2-stack DPDA, then we know 2-stack DPDA is not subset-or-equal to DPDA.
3) this is hard to say, will attempt later
4) certainly not, by the same argument as for (2).

As for (3) - I strongly suspect that a 2-stack DPDA can simulate a deterministic TM, which would imply NPDA is a subset of 2-stack DPDA. To prove this, one needs to show how to simulate the operation of any TM using a 2-stack DPDA. I think something like this visualization maybe suffices...

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|Z|_|_|_|_|_|_| |_|_|_|_|_|_|Z|
   stack #1      ^  stack #2
                 TM
```

The input is originally recorded entirely on stack #2. To move right, the TM pops from stack #2 and pushes to stack #1. To move left, the TM pops from stack #1 and pushes to stack #2. The current tape cell is always the top of stack #2. The 2-stack DPDA can do whatever a deterministic TM can do in terms of states and transitions; and it can use the two stacks to simulate a tape as above. For instance, a TM to accept the nondeterministic context-free language of all palindromes works as follows:

1. check the first cell. if empty, halt-accept. Otherwise, write a blank and move to state End(s) where s is the symbol observed.
2. while in state End(s), move right until you find a blank. Then, move left and enter state Check(s).
3. while in state Check(s), confirm the observed symbol is s. If not, then halt-accept if blank and halt-reject otherwise. Otherwise, write a blank and enter the state IsFinished and move left.
4. while in state IsFinished, check to see whether the tape cell is blank. If so, halt-accept. Otherwise, enter state Start and move left.
5. while in state Start, move left until you find a blank. Then, move right and enter the initial state again.

Example on a TM vs a 2-stack DPDA:

```
DTM                2-stack DPDA               
-------            --------------------
tape     State     Stack #1    Stack #2
B11011B            Z           11011Z
 ^       initial               ^
BB1011B            ZB          1011Z
  ^      End(1)                ^
BB1011B            ZB1         011Z
   ^     End(1)                ^
BB1011B            ZB10        11Z
    ^    End(1)                ^
BB1011B            ZB101       1Z
     ^   End(1)
BB1011B            ZB1011      Z
      ^  End(1)                ^           
BB1011B            ZB101       1Z
     ^   Check(1)              ^
BB101BB            ZB10        1BZ
    ^    IsFin                 ^
BB101BB            ZB1         01BZ
   ^     Start                 ^
BB101BB            ZB          101BZ
  ^      Start                 ^
BB101BB            Z           B101BZ
 ^       Start                 ^
BB101BB            ZB          101BZ
  ^      Initial               ^
BBB01BB            ZBB         01BZ
   ^     End(1)                ^
BBB01BB            ZBB0        1BZ
    ^    End(1)                ^
BBB01BB            ZBB01       BZ
     ^   End(1)                ^
BBB01BB            ZBB0        1BZ
    ^    Check(1)              ^
BBB0BBB            ZBB         0BBZ
   ^     IsFin                 ^
BBB0BBB            ZB          B0BBZ
  ^      Start                 ^
BBB0BBB            ZBB         0BBZ
   ^     initial               ^
BBBBBBB            ZBBB        BBZ
    ^    End(0)                ^
BBBBBBB            ZBB         BBBZ
   ^     Check(0)              ^
BBBBBBB            ZBB         BBBZ
   ^     halt-accept           ^
```

Based on this example, I think the construction is correct and 2-stack DPDAs are equivalent to Turing machines. Therefore, NPDA is subset-or-equal to 2-stack DPDA.